# Mocking nested function with Mox (Elixir)

Tags: mocking, elixir

I am new to both mocking and Elixir, and trying to use the mocking library Mox to improve my tests coverage (mocking the dependencies), I was hoping to be able to create tests for most of my most critical status processors, and other calculations that my application need.

So I have been able to use the library, and as a first approach I got this mocked function to test fine:

```
test "Mocked OK response test" do
    Parsers.MockMapsApi
    |> expect(:parse_get_distance_duration, fn _ -> {:ok, "test_body", 200} end)

    assert {:ok, "test_body", 200} == Parsers.MockMapsApi.parse_get_distance_duration({:ok, "", 200})
end
```

It is clear that this test is useless, since what I wanted to mock was this NESTED function from within another function, but only got to mock directly the function that was being called in the test.

So, pointing now my actual problem for a more simple test, that illustrates very well the scenario:

```
def get_time_diff_to_point(point_time) do
            point_time
            |> DateConverter.from_timestamp()
            |> Timex.diff(Timex.now(), :seconds)
            |> Result.success()
    end
```

Clearly the Timex.now() will give me a new timestamp each time, making it impossible to test the calcucation successfully without a mock. So the real question is, How do I mock a NESTED function within the actual function being tested? In this case, I expect Timex.now() to give me the same value every time I run my test... Here's what I got so far (clearly not working, but I think illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
test "Mocked time difference test" do
    Utils.MockTimeDistance
    |> expect(:Timex.now(), fn -> #DateTime<2018-01-28 20:13:43.137007Z> end)

    assert {:ok, 4217787010} == Utils.TimeDistance.get_time_diff_to_point(5734957348)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mox approach makes this distinction explicit:  Your current code has a very specific dependency on `Timex.now`, and cannot possibly be compiled without it.

In your mind, though, your code only has a dependency on being able to find out the current time, and it is this dependency which you wish to mock during the test.

This is the reason that Mox insists on only mocking behaviours: you are forced to specifically identify the external dependencies that must be controlled.

So, to embrace the Mox way, what you need to do is either:

1. find a time library that provides a behaviour, -or-
2. wrap `Timex.now` in a module of your own that implements a behaviour Mox can work with.

For instance, you could write something like:

```
defmodule TimeProvider do
  @callback now() :: DateTime.t

  @behaviour __MODULE__
  @impl __MODULE__
  def now(), do: Timex.now()
end
```

Now, instead of calling `Timex.now` from your `get_time_diff...` method, you need to use a dependency injection strategy to call out to an implementation of `TimeProvider`.  Two ways for doing dependency injection: use `Application.get_env(app, key)` to retrieve the module from config (set it to `TimeProvider` in config.exs, but overwrite it to MockTimeProvider in test), or set up the module as a default parameter that is only ever overridden in tests.

```
def get_time_diff_to_point(point_time, time_provider \\ TimeProvider) do
            point_time
            |> DateConverter.from_timestamp()
            |> Timex.diff(time_provider.now(), :seconds)
            |> Result.success()
end
```

Mox would need the following setup:  somewhere in your `test_helper.exs`:

```
Mox.defmock(MockTime, for: TimeProvider)
```

and in your test:

```
test "time_diff" do
  expect(MockTime, :now, fn -> DateTime.from_unix!(0) end)
  assert get_time_diff_to_point(DateTime.from_unix!(1), MockTimeProvider) == ...
end
```

Note that in general, mocking time is both hard and important.  This is a simple example, where you know that none of the other function calls in the code-under-test is going to be time-dependent, and `now()` will only be called once: you can treat it as normal mocking: but beware timing while testing in more involved/time aware code.

**EDIT:**

After a bit more thought, you can DRY up your code and only do dependency injection in one place by adding a single layer of abstraction:

```
defmodule MyApp.Time do
  def now() do
    time_provider = Application.get_env(:my_app, :time_provider)
    time_provider.now()
  end
  defmodule TimeProvider do
    @callback now() :: DateTime.t
  end
  defmodule DefaultTimeProvider do
    @behaviour TimeProvider
    @impl TimeProvider
    def now(), do: Timex.now()
  end
end
```

In your config.exs, you'll need:

```
config :myapp, time_provider: MyApp.Time.DefaultTimeProvider
```

And in your test setup, you'll need:

```
Mox.defmock(MockTime, for: TimeProvider)
Application.put_env(:my_app, :time_provider, MockTime)
```

Which simplifies your example (and, importantly, *all* other usages) by removing the optional parameter:

```
def get_time_diff_to_point(point_time) do
  point_time
  |> DateConverter.from_timestamp()
  |> Timex.diff(MyApp.Time.now(), :seconds)
  |> Result.success()
end
```

Both approaches have merit- experiment with both, and learn which situations work best with each.

Comment: Okay, so I got the conceptual part and added the same module TimeProvider which you did, changed the Utils.TimeDistance now() for the new TimeProvider.now(), adding also a defmock for it.

Even tho, the nested function isn't changed after doing so, testing a new result every time, is there any syntax I'm missing there?

test "Mocked time difference test" do
        Utils.TimeProviderMock
        |> expect(:now, fn -> DateTime.from_iso8601("2015-01-23T23:50:07Z") end)
    
        assert "2018-05-15 23:37:48" == TimeDistance.calculate_estimated_time_of_arrival(4345345)
    end

Comment: Yes, you need the dependency injection to occur. Sorry I wasn't more explicit about that in my answer, I'll update.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have even learned how to do dependency injection in functional languages now hehe.

Comment: @ChrisMeyer how would you go about providing a mock only for unit tests? I would like to use a mock for unit tests, but not for integration tests.